# IBM Worklight - Worklight Application Center integration with WebSeal

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, webseal, worklight-appcenter

Is this possible to integrate Worklight Application Center with WebSeal?

I tried integrated the solution as described by the link

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.express.doc%2Finfo%2Fexp%2Fae%2Ftsec_sso_ws_step3_sso_create_junct.html

But the login form of the Worklight Application Center still appears after users login by the webseal.

Answer (score 2):

I think you will find the article and sample project linked from this page helpful:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24034222

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. The Application Center authentication and authorization mechanism uses the J2EE standard so is completely based upon the security layer of the application server.
So you need only to configure the definition between WebSeal and WebSphere Application Server especially the creation of a junction and by enabling SSO using the TAI.

This concerns the AppCenter console. Concerning the AppCenter client as it uses basic authentication to call the Application Services it should also work.

Comment: Bruno, does this apply to Worklight 6.0 as well? If so, the article linked below by billdodd should be updated...

Comment: Idan, I've added some info in the answer : the WebSeal integration works with the AppCenter console since there is no AppCenter configuration to do. Bill's article is only valid for Worklight and cannot concern Application Center since Application Center doesn't use the Worklight security mechanism.

Comment: Bruno, I did created a junction to WAS, which contained Worklight App Center with option  "-b supply" as described by the link below, however webseal does not show any reponses when WL App Center return the login form ( In Other Application, webseal return an error). Do you have any idea of how to deal with the problem? PS: the link: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.express.doc%2Fae%2Ftsec_sso_ws_step3_sso_create_junct.html

Comment: It depends on how you use WebSeal : if you use SSO, it means that you are already signed to WebSeal before invoking the App Center console URL. If you are not already authenticated to WebSeal (as it seems) you cannot use the login form of the App Center console. You have to use the WebSeal login form. You can look at the WebSeal infocenter about this configuration : http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/tivihelp/v2r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.itame.doc_6.1.1%2Fam611_webseal_admin210.htm&path=4_8_1_3_1_5_1_3. For further help you can contact the IBM support.